# Apache performance issue on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, windows-server-2012

I have my server hosted on a machine using Windows Server 2012 operating system. 
I have installed the XAMPP 1.7.3 version which provides APACHE 2.2 with it.
My server machine runs 24 X 7.

After running properly for about 4 months now I observe that the Web server (Apache instance) is getting crashed frequently (On an interval of 2-3 days).

When I see the Windows Task Manager I see two instances of httpd.exe in it, of which one instance is idle (not much cpu as well as memory usage), whereas the other instance uses a lot of memory and CPU (It varies between 80 - 100%) and finally crashes the entire web server.

This is causing a lot of problem as this server is my production server.

Server Machine specification - 
 1. RAM - 4 GB of which 2.6 GB is usable.
 2. OS  - Windows server 2012 64 bit.
 3. Processor - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50 GHz 2.49 GHz.

Please suggest a solution on whether it is possible to fine tune the apache settings to reduce the CPU usage and avoid the crashing of apache service.

Thanks in advance.